# round decimal to nearest 10th

Tags: java

need to round my answer to nearest10th.

```
    double finalPrice = everyMile + 2.8;
    DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    this.answerField.setText("£" + fmt.format(finalPrice) + " Approx");
```

the above code rounds a whole number to the nearest 10th however it wont round a decimal. e.g 2.44 should be rounded to 2.40

Comment: Seconding Jon Skeet's last remark, please be aware that **no** number written in decimal as x.1, x.2, x.3, x.4, x.6, x.7, x.8, or x.9 is represented exactly as a floating-point number.

Comment: i don't understand what you said

Comment: Take the time to understand it as it is important.

Comment: lol. could you please explain?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems summary: floats and money don't mix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change a bit the pattern to hard-code the final zero:

```
double finalPrice = 2.46;
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.0'0'");
System.out.println("£" + fmt.format(finalPrice) + " Approx");
```

Now, if you're manipulating real-world money, you'd better not use double, but int or BigInteger.

Comment: MAGICAL.

lol

worked. so by says '0' it means physically stick 0 as the final number no matter what?

Comment: sweet, thanks for your help. i posted the same thing in a different forum, after 4 hours they sarcastically reffered me to google.(which i tried before)

you guys where super fast lol

Answer (score 10):

Use [`BigDecimal`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead.

You really, really don't want to use binary floating point for monetary values.

EDIT: `round()` doesn't let you specify the decimal places, only the significant figures. Here's a somewhat fiddly technique, but it works (assuming you want to truncate, basically):

```
import java.math.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("20.44");
        bd = bd.movePointRight(1);
        BigInteger floor = bd.toBigInteger();
        bd = new BigDecimal(floor).movePointLeft(1);
        System.out.println(bd);
    }
}
```

I'd like to hope there's a simpler way of doing this...

Comment: Simpler and faster way was given in @Peter's answer.

Comment: @Vadzim: That's calling the `BigDecimal(double)` constructor, which is rarely a good idea IMO. And we still don't know what the OP wants to do in terms of rounding vs truncating. But hey, it's good to have multiple options...

Answer (score 6):

This outputs `2.40`

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(2.44);
System.out.println(bd.setScale(1,RoundingMode.HALF_UP).setScale(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
double finalPriceRoundedToNearestTenth = Math.round(10.0 * finalPrice) / 10.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
double d = 25.642;
String s = String.format("£ %.2f", Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.1f", d).replace(',', '.')));
System.out.println(s);
```

I know this is a stupid way, but it works.