# how to round off a double value to the nearest 0.05 in java

Tags: java

i want to round off a double value to its nearest 0.05 in java.
eg: 54.625 to 54.65

or

32.1885 to 32.19 etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [round decimal to nearest 10th](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887826/round-decimal-to-nearest-10th)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235814/rounding-a-decimal-to-the-nearest-0-05

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857497/roundoff-double-values-in-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java

Answer (score 1):

```
double foo = 54.625;
foo = (int)(foo * 20.0 + 0.5) / 20.0;
```

This is quick and dirty - it doesn't handle negative numbers correctly, for instance.  But for simple problems, it's a simple solution.

Comment: this rounds to the nearest 0.01 and it can get a rounding erro in the division.

Comment: paul the above solution works. but it gives the output as 16.490000000000002 instead of 16.49. how do i truncate it??

Comment: Shilpa, that is how floating point numbers work.  If you want exact output, use BigDecimal.

Comment: Ok, now it rounds to 0.05, not to 0.01.

Comment: We can use also java.text.DecimalFormat and then Double.parseDouble

Comment: @Davide I bet if you timed it, you'd find my solution works 100x faster than converting to text and back.

Comment: @PaulTomblin Yes this is sure. My answers was only an alternative